# How do I get the class of an array via Class.forName(...)?

Tags: java, reflection

Let's say I have a method `do` expecting an array of arguments of some class `E`:

```
public class D {

    public void do(E ..arg){}

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class z = Class.forName("D");
    Class e = Class.forName("E");
    Method m = z.getDeclaredMethod("do", e);
}
```

I want to get the method and the class using reflection, but this throws a

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Comment: do is not a static method, I tried z.getMethod("do",e); didn't work

Comment: I also tried z.getMethod("do",Object[].class); That also didn't work;

Comment: It's in class D.

Comment: D is the public class !!

Comment: You are trying to to get a reference to a method with the name `do` and a single parameter of type `E`. But the method has a `E[]` parameter...

Comment: Does that code compile at all? I might be a bit rusty in java but I'm not 100% sure you can call a method `do` and varargs with `..` instead of `...`

Comment: Yes, but how to do it with use of Class e = Class.forName("E"); in Method m = z.getDeclaredMethod("do",e);

Comment: You can't do it with `e`, because that's not what the method expects.

Comment: Is there any way, I can get "e" as an array of "E" using reflection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`do` expects an array of `E`.

So instead of passing `getDeclaredMethod(...)` `e`, pass it `E[].class`:

```
Method m = z.getDeclaredMethod("do", E[].class);
```

If you have to use `Class.forName(...)`, you'll need to modify the name a bit. If you print out any object array's class, you'll see that it has a `[L` in the front and a `;` at the end. Just add that to your argument and it should work:

```
Class<?> e = Class.forName("[L" + "E" + ";");
Method m = z.getDeclaredMethod("do", e);
```

You could also write a method that returns the class-name of an array with any amount of dimensions:

```
public static String getArrayClassName(int dimensions, String base) {
    return "[".repeat(dimensions) + "L" + base + ";";
}
```

Comment: Is there any way, I can get "e" as an array of "E" using reflection? I have a requirement to do with Class e = Class.forName("E");

Comment: Actually I have the String "E" and using this I want to getMethod.

Comment: @AnshulKhandelwal There is, give me a sec.

Comment: See also [`Class::arrayType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#arrayType()) since Java 12.